# Best way to cascade editor templates in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, templates

Given a template that looks like this?

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-6">@Html.LabelFor(_ => _.A)</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.EditorFor(_ => _.A)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(_ => _.A, null, new { @class = "help-block" })
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-md-6">@Html.LabelFor(_ => _.B)</label>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            @Html.EditorFor(_ => _.B)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(_ => _.B, null, new { @class = "help-block" })
        </div>
    </div>
   (and repeat for every field)
```

How can I parameterise this correctly. Editor templates don't seem to cascade well.

In other words I think what is needed is a template that takes a lambda as a model argument?

`TemplateFor(x => x.Other)` where the template contains all the boilerplate markup, and calls `EditorFor`, `LabelFor` and `ValidationMessageFor` in the correct places.

The `EditorFor` needs to select the correct template based on the type of the property, as it normally does.

Comment: What about `@Html.EditorForModel()` or `@Html.EditorFor(x => x)` have you tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put this all in your editor template. For example, you can create a editor template for `String`:

**Views\Shared\EditorTemplates\String.cshtml**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-6">@Html.Label("")</label>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue)
        @Html.ValidationMessage("", null, new { @class = "help-block" })
    </div>
</div>
```

And, then, for any `string` property, you just need the following in your view:

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.SomeStringProperty)
```

Notice, two things about the editor template:

1. There's no `*For` methods, but rather just the regular HTML helpers. This lets you sidestep the issue of needing to carry around the initial expression.
2. The regular methods, however, require you to specify the property name as a string, but thankfully, Razor gives you an out: if you pass an empty string, it will put the right string in there for you.

Rinse and repeat for all your other types. For a more in depth overview, see my post, [Display Templates and Editor Templates for Fun and Profit](http://cpratt.co/displaytemplates-and-editortemplates-for-fun-and-profit/).